# Project file was not found

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, azure-devops

I have an existing TFS project that has a structure similar to this :

[image: Source tree]

I created a solution within the framework directory that have 2 projects.

I have then added the Cerberus & Cerberus.Mvc to the OnFaitQuoi solution as existing projects. (note that the cerberus solution was checked in previously).

When I checked in my project, I got some errors including those :

[image: TFS Errors]

Does it means that this scenario is not supported by TFS azure or only that I did an error somewhere ?

Comment: If these errors are when you're building using Team Build, check your build definition and make sure that the "framework" folder is included in the buidl workspace. You should also make sure that the relative paths in the build workspace are the same as your local machine

Comment: Well the TFS folder is rigorously exactly the same as the physical path on my machine. (even the SLn has this line : "Cerberus", "..\Framework\Cerberus\Cerberus.csproj") so it might not be that :/ tho to verify that the framework folder is included in the build workspace how should I check that ?

Comment: On your TFS build definition, right click and "Edit build Definition" then select the workspace tab. This will show the mappings between the folders in TFS and what the build pulls down to the build server.

Comment: @JamesReed it was apparently what was required! You should create an answer so I can credit you correctly :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these errors are when you're building using Team Build, check your build definition and make sure that the "framework" folder is included in the buidl workspace. You should also make sure that the relative paths in the build workspace are the same as your local machine.

To chech the build definition workspace right click on the build definition in team explorer and select "Edit build definition" then select the workspace tab. This will show the mappings between the folders in TFS and what the build pulls down to the build server

Answer (score 2):

Go to Solution Explorer. Find your project, right click and select Add Items to Folder. Select your missing Project to add it to the sln.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any project dependencies set up on your solution. Right click on the solution and select Project dependencies.

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/562ae95f-e042-45c2-9821-62cac49d0152

Comment: After you add dependencies, close Visual studio, it will prompt to save changes to the csproj file, select "yes" and the reopen. If the file does not exist in the project, you can use the file browser to browse to the file, and then check in the file you want.