# Project Build fails on TFS azure because of the project reference

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

MVC Web Application Solution fails to build on the TFS azure (.visualstudio.com) because project has reference to another shared library project. Build Log:

```
Build started 2/26/2013 12:53:17 AM.
    Project "C:\a\src\Development\[Main Project].sln" on node 1 (default targets).
    ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
      Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
    C:\a\src\Development\[Main Project].sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "C:\a\src\Development\..\..\[Sub Project Root]\Development\[Sub Project]\[Sub Project].csproj" was not found.
```

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: I think this is a build workspace problem. Check that the relative path in your build workspace are the same as in TFS / local machine. [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898125/project-file-was-not-found/14940645#14940645) is very similar

Comment: It was indeed workspace folder mapping. By default subfolder was missing and mapping for the Sub Project has to be there as well.

Comment: I'll vote to close this question then. If you're feeling generous please upvite my answer on the other question.

Comment: James, can't upvote any answers as my reputation is too low :-) Will do once I'll reach 15!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add your project file .csproj to your source control, deployed on cloud